# Python: Delete lines from except certain criteria

Tags: python, criteria, keyword

I am trying to delete lines from a file using specific criteria
The script i have seems to work but i have to add to many Or statements
Is there a way i can make an variable that holds all the criterias i would like to remove from the files?

Example code

```
with open("AW.txt", "r+", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    new_f = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for line in new_f:
        if "PPL"not in line.split() or "PPLX"not in line.split() or "PPLC"not in line.split():
            f.write(line)
    f.truncate()
```

I was more thinking in this way but it fails when i add multiple criterias

```
output = []
with open('AW.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    criteria = 'PPL'
    output =[line for line in lines if criteria not in line]

f.writelines(output)
```

Regards

Comment: May be use grep or sed and it could be done in one line?

`grep -v "PPL[X|C]*" file.txt` works?

Comment: sed alternative would be `sed -E -i -e "/PPL(X|C)?/d" AW.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to your rescue which will reduce the number of statements and checks in the code. If you have a list of criteria which can be dynamic, let's call the list of criteria `crit_list`, then the code would look like-

```
import re 
with open("AW.txt", "r+", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    new_f = f.readlines()
    crit_list = ['PPL', 'PPLC', 'PPLX']    # Can use any number of criterions 
    obj = re.compile(r'%s' % ('|'.join(crit_list)))
    out_lines = [line for line in new_f if not obj.search(line)]
    f.truncate(0)
    f.seek(0)
    f.writelines(out_lines)
```

Use of `regex` makes it look different from how OP had posted. Let me explain the two lines containing the regex-

```
obj = re.compile(r'%s' % ('|'.join(crit_list)))
```

This line creates a regex object with the regular expression `'PPL|PPLX|PPLC'` which means `match at least one of these strings` in the given line which can be thought of as a substitute for using as many `or`s in the code as there are criteria.

```
out_lines = [line for line in new_f if not obj.search(line)]
```

This statement means, search for the given criteria in the given line and if at least of them is found, preserve that line.

Hope that clears your doubts.

Comment: Thanks for this
It is written little different but does what it needs to do

Comment: @Unwanted Explained the two non-obvious lines for your understanding if you are not familiar with the regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks to both you and @Dex for helping me out on this and willing to learn me some Python :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can get compare each list item with each criteria and get only those items that meet the criteria. Then simply get all lines which meet all the criterias.

For example, this can be done like (**EDITED CODE**):

```
with open('AW.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    criterias = ["PPL","PPLX","PPLC"]
    conditioned_lines = [[line for criteria in criterias if criteria not in line] for line in lines]
    output = [criteria_lines[0] for criteria_lines in conditioned_lines if len(criteria_lines) == len(criterias)]
    f.truncate(0)
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(''.join(output))
```

Comment: i am getting this error on your code
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

For everyone else,
Sorry to be fuzzy lol 
What i mean is that i have a text file with a lot of lines
The criterias given are the ones that needs to be removed from the file
All the rest that does not met this criteria needs to stay in the file 

Regards

Comment: Even if the file was open, it would append the contents of the output to the file rather than replacing the file contents with the output-list contents. I have modified my answer which removes the lines from the file containing criteria words.

Comment: Thanks 
The error was because the f.writelines(output) was out of the box (just a tab and error was gone 
The script does not seems to remove the lines nor add them
Can this because the lines are tab delimited?
Line.split can be applied here right?
Regards

Comment: Please try the code now, I've edited it. It'll replace the contents of "AW.txt" with updated lines.

Comment: Just what i needed 
Thanks for the help :-)
Appreciate it

Comment: You don't have to close the file explicitly, `with` context manager takes care of that.

Comment: @yabhishek yes that's right, thanks. I've edited it out.

Comment: May i ask you 1 more thing 
how can i turn this script around?
I mean now i filter out what i dont want 
But how can i make a filter of what i want to keep?

I ws thinking of removing the not in the line "[[line for criteria in criterias if criteria not in line] for line in lines]" But that does not work lol

Comment: This check is wrong `len(criteria_lines) == len(criterias)` as it assumes that all the criteria should be present in a line in order to save that line. However @Unwanted wants a line to be saved if it has at least one of the criterias. This check is causing the output_list to be empty.

Comment: @Unwanted You can look at my answer for your purpose and remove `not` from the line containing `not obj.search(line)` and it will serve your reverse purpose.

Comment: @yabhishek  
It might be me but i cant find the not obj.search(line) line in your code 
And the only not in the script is in line "[[line for criteria in criterias if criteria not in line] for line in lines]" Removing that one will cause the output file empty and removing the check will make the run fail
Let me try to figure this out as i will learn from this 
thanks for the push :-)

Comment: My answer is different. You are referring to @Dex's answer. My answer is one of the other two answers and this is the comment section of the answer you are referring to. If you post a question, please try to look at other relevant answers as you may get better answers to your questions by going through all of the answers.

Comment: Apologies @yabhishek

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

output = []
with open('AW.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    criteria = 'PPL'
    output = re.sub("^.*[Crit1|Crit2|Crit3].*","")

f.writelines(output)
```

This will remove the lines. but it will not print them out in the writelines statement
your question was a little fuzzy, asking for lines to be deleted but then trying to write them out
add as many criteria as you want like this